# In-built sum function in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, built-in

```
def sum_elements(l):
    sum = 0
    string = ""
    k = 0
    for i in l:
        if type(i) is int:
            sum = sum + l[k]
            k += 1
        elif type(i)is str:
            string = string + str(l[k])
            k += 1
    print "sum of integers in list" + str(sum)
    print "sum of strings in list" + string
```

Python has a built-in function `sum` to find sum of all elements of a list. In case the list is integer numbers `sum_elements([1, 2, 3])`, it will return 6. `sum` function works for a list of strings as well. `sum_elements(["hello", "world"])` returns `helloworld`. I have written an implementation for the `sum` built-in function in the above code. It works.

I am a newbie in Python, I just want to know if it's correct or is there any better approach?

Are there are any links available for the python built-in functions source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to access an element by its index. If the list is not empty and all elements are of the same type, you can code as follows:

```
>>> def sum_elements(l):
...     s = l[0]
...     for element in l[1:]:
...         s += element
...     return s
... 
>>> sum_elements([1, 2, 3])
6
>>> sum_elements(['hello', 'world'])
'helloworld'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
from operator import add
def sum_elements(l):
    return reduce(add, l)
```

Comment: NameError: name 'reduce' is not defined